# ¿Cómo aplicar efecto hover a un poligono (triangulo) y a un icono formado por paths en svg para que muestre texto "Apartado 1" fuera de la imagen?

Tags: html, css, svg, hover

[image: Lo que busco es que al pasar el cursor el icono (imagen) desaparezca y aparezca el texto "Apartado 1" sobre la zona gris del triángulo. Intenté hacerlo pero solo conseguí aplicar el efecto hover al triángulo.]

```css
.apartados{
 
 

}
.apartados:hover{
fill:#ffcd00;
}
.apartados:hover + text{
fill-opacity:1;
pointer-events:none;
text-align: center;
}

text{
fill-opacity:0;
font-family:OpenSans-ExtraboldItalic;
 font-size:6.5px;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.0" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 1366 768" enable-background="new 0 0 1366 768" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Apartado_5">
 <defs>
  <polygon  id="SVGID_1_" points="219,54 1103,54 661.003,627   "/>
 </defs>
 <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
  <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"  overflow="visible"/>
 </clipPath>
 <linearGradient id="SVGID_3_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="219" y1="340.5" x2="1103" y2="340.5">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#8F9493"/>
  <stop  offset="0.4845" style="stop-color:#C3CCCB"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#8E9392"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="apartados" clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)" fill="url(#SVGID_3_)" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="219,54 1103,54 
  661.003,627  "/>
 <g id="icono_5_1_" clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)">
  <g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <path fill="#143B74" d="M790.094,147.851L672.824,90.783c-5.12-2.501-10.395-2.724-14.965-1.062v-0.005l-11.16,3.286h8.515
      c-1.638,2.21-2.931,4.848-3.74,7.881l-62.014,230.405c-3.512,13.058,3.056,28.226,14.664,33.878l117.283,57.068
      c1.25,0.605,2.499,1.072,3.74,1.41l-4.628,5.724l9.83-2.772h-0.008c5.767-2.091,10.455-7.171,12.416-14.458l62.014-230.419
      C808.284,168.671,801.716,153.499,790.094,147.851z"/>
     <path fill="#D0E6F6" d="M704.967,428.526l-117.262-57.074c-11.63-5.643-18.198-20.811-14.679-33.864l62.007-230.41
      c3.519-13.057,15.774-19.058,27.389-13.41l117.277,57.074c11.615,5.658,18.183,20.824,14.664,33.877l-61.999,230.405
      C728.851,428.187,716.582,434.182,704.967,428.526z"/>
     <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M705.172,421.968l-114.513-55.731c-9.029-4.395-14.128-16.186-11.41-26.334l61.668-229.148
      c2.733-10.153,12.269-14.814,21.306-10.424l114.507,55.735c9.028,4.396,14.149,16.187,11.402,26.334l-61.654,229.143
      C723.738,421.697,714.209,426.364,705.172,421.968z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
     <linearGradient id="SVGID_4_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="588.5148" y1="259.0109" x2="805.7188" y2="259.0109">
      <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#5D676B"/>
      <stop  offset="0.4845" style="stop-color:#808B90"/>
      <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#5D676B"/>
     </linearGradient>
     <path fill="url(#SVGID_4_)" d="M790.094,147.851L672.824,90.783c-5.12-2.501-10.395-2.724-14.965-1.062v-0.005l-11.16,3.286
      h8.515c-1.638,2.21-2.931,4.848-3.74,7.881l-62.014,230.405c-3.512,13.058,3.056,28.226,14.664,33.878l117.283,57.068
      c1.25,0.605,2.499,1.072,3.74,1.41l-4.628,5.724l9.83-2.772h-0.008c5.767-2.091,10.455-7.171,12.416-14.458l62.014-230.419
      C808.284,168.671,801.716,153.499,790.094,147.851z"/>
     <linearGradient id="SVGID_5_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="572.0767" y1="261.1499" x2="795.3118" y2="261.1499">
      <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#8F9493"/>
      <stop  offset="0.4845" style="stop-color:#C3CCCB"/>
      <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#8E9392"/>
     </linearGradient>
     <path fill="url(#SVGID_5_)" d="M704.967,428.526l-117.262-57.074c-11.63-5.643-18.198-20.811-14.679-33.864l62.007-230.41
      c3.519-13.057,15.774-19.058,27.389-13.41l117.277,57.074c11.615,5.658,18.183,20.824,14.664,33.877l-61.999,230.405
      C728.851,428.187,716.582,434.182,704.967,428.526z"/>
     <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M705.172,421.968l-114.513-55.731c-9.029-4.395-14.128-16.186-11.41-26.334l61.668-229.148
      c2.733-10.153,12.269-14.814,21.306-10.424l114.507,55.735c9.028,4.396,14.149,16.187,11.402,26.334l-61.654,229.143
      C723.738,421.697,714.209,426.364,705.172,421.968z"/>
    </g>
    <g opacity="0.4">
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M695.673,148.052l-13.062-6.11c-1.198-0.562-1.918-1.972-1.587-3.129l0,0
      c0.323-1.166,1.579-1.652,2.799-1.085l13.056,6.109c1.212,0.572,1.932,1.972,1.602,3.134l0,0
      C698.142,148.142,696.885,148.619,695.673,148.052z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M726.801,162.609l-19.255-9.005c-1.219-0.576-1.939-1.976-1.602-3.138l0,0
      c0.33-1.166,1.594-1.647,2.792-1.081l19.263,9.005c1.22,0.572,1.933,1.981,1.594,3.138l0,0
      C729.27,162.69,728.014,163.171,726.801,162.609z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M672.898,197.464l-13.056-6.11c-1.204-0.572-1.924-1.981-1.594-3.138l0,0
      c0.323-1.162,1.58-1.647,2.799-1.081l13.056,6.105c1.22,0.571,1.924,1.981,1.594,3.137l0,0
      C675.374,197.545,674.11,198.03,672.898,197.464z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M700.654,210.435l-19.263-9.01c-1.22-0.567-1.939-1.971-1.609-3.138l0,0
      c0.345-1.157,1.594-1.637,2.807-1.076l19.256,9.005c1.219,0.567,1.932,1.972,1.608,3.134l0,0
      C703.108,210.521,701.859,211.001,700.654,210.435z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M657.14,140.032l-8.163-3.814c-1.205-0.567-1.925-1.967-1.587-3.134l0,0
      c0.338-1.163,1.572-1.648,2.792-1.077l8.162,3.81c1.213,0.572,1.925,1.976,1.594,3.137l0,0
      C659.6,140.118,658.359,140.599,657.14,140.032z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M682.302,161.819l-24.942-11.667c-1.213-0.572-1.925-1.976-1.594-3.134l0,0
      c0.33-1.171,1.579-1.643,2.791-1.085l24.943,11.662c1.212,0.567,1.918,1.976,1.587,3.134l0,0
      C684.763,161.895,683.507,162.381,682.302,161.819z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M660.482,171.628l-8.163-3.814c-1.197-0.572-1.91-1.966-1.594-3.138l0,0
      c0.339-1.162,1.587-1.642,2.799-1.076l8.155,3.814c1.212,0.567,1.939,1.972,1.609,3.138l0,0
      C662.95,171.714,661.694,172.195,660.482,171.628z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M704.849,232.417l-21.791-10.191c-1.213-0.567-1.939-1.971-1.602-3.134l0,0
      c0.33-1.171,1.594-1.652,2.799-1.085l21.797,10.196c1.205,0.572,1.925,1.962,1.602,3.138l0,0
      C707.31,232.502,706.069,232.984,704.849,232.417z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M652.533,187.924l-5.246-2.447c-1.212-0.567-1.918-1.967-1.587-3.134l0,0
      c0.33-1.163,1.587-1.648,2.799-1.082l5.238,2.448c1.198,0.572,1.918,1.972,1.594,3.138l0,0
      C655.001,188.015,653.745,188.491,652.533,187.924z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M648.764,206.192l-6.502-3.048c-1.219-0.572-1.932-1.967-1.594-3.138l0,0
      c0.331-1.162,1.58-1.643,2.799-1.076l6.501,3.043c1.213,0.567,1.925,1.971,1.587,3.134l0,0
      C651.218,206.268,649.984,206.754,648.764,206.192z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M674.073,218.026l-17.154-8.029c-1.22-0.567-1.918-1.966-1.587-3.134l0,0
      c0.323-1.157,1.58-1.642,2.792-1.076l17.147,8.019c1.219,0.576,1.925,1.977,1.602,3.134l0,0
      C676.542,218.107,675.294,218.593,674.073,218.026z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M652.077,217.741l-12.328-5.758c-1.219-0.572-1.924-1.986-1.601-3.142l0,0
      c0.33-1.167,1.587-1.648,2.799-1.082l12.321,5.767c1.213,0.572,1.939,1.972,1.609,3.138l0,0
      C654.539,217.822,653.282,218.307,652.077,217.741z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M723.554,241.213l-7.92-3.705c-1.219-0.572-1.933-1.971-1.595-3.134l0,0
      c0.323-1.166,1.58-1.652,2.785-1.081l7.935,3.7c1.204,0.567,1.917,1.971,1.587,3.134l0,0
      C726.022,241.294,724.766,241.77,723.554,241.213z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M690.854,185.825l-21.805-10.191c-1.205-0.567-1.918-1.967-1.594-3.134l0,0
      c0.33-1.162,1.587-1.648,2.792-1.081l21.805,10.191c1.205,0.572,1.932,1.981,1.594,3.138l0,0
      C693.315,185.91,692.065,186.391,690.854,185.825z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M692.83,176.753l-37.983-17.772c-1.219-0.563-1.933-1.972-1.602-3.129l0,0
      c0.338-1.172,1.587-1.658,2.799-1.086l37.983,17.773c1.22,0.572,1.932,1.962,1.602,3.134l0,0
      C695.291,176.838,694.042,177.319,692.83,176.753z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M671.605,186.844l-21.797-10.2c-1.213-0.572-1.918-1.967-1.595-3.134l0,0
      c0.331-1.162,1.587-1.647,2.799-1.081l21.798,10.2c1.219,0.562,1.924,1.966,1.587,3.134l0,0
      C674.073,186.925,672.824,187.406,671.605,186.844z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M707.384,193.563l-7.927-3.705c-1.213-0.567-1.925-1.972-1.587-3.129l0,0
      c0.331-1.171,1.572-1.653,2.792-1.086l7.927,3.7c1.213,0.572,1.925,1.982,1.587,3.138l0,0
      C709.845,193.648,708.596,194.13,707.384,193.563z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M766.511,180.02l-7.913-3.7c-1.22-0.567-1.932-1.972-1.602-3.134l0,0
      c0.338-1.166,1.594-1.647,2.799-1.085l7.927,3.705c1.198,0.572,1.918,1.981,1.587,3.137l0,0
      C768.994,180.106,767.73,180.586,766.511,180.02z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M670.981,206.569l-26.206-12.258c-1.22-0.562-1.918-1.966-1.587-3.129l0,0
      c0.33-1.176,1.579-1.657,2.792-1.09l26.206,12.257c1.212,0.567,1.918,1.972,1.594,3.134l0,0
      C673.442,206.654,672.2,207.135,670.981,206.569z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M670.76,136.394l-19.263-9c-1.22-0.576-1.925-1.981-1.602-3.134l0,0
      c0.338-1.176,1.594-1.652,2.799-1.09l19.264,9.015c1.212,0.567,1.939,1.962,1.602,3.134l0,0
      C673.222,136.479,671.965,136.965,670.76,136.394z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M648.639,226.155l-22.312-10.443c-1.205-0.572-1.925-1.967-1.587-3.138l0,0
      c0.331-1.158,1.58-1.643,2.799-1.077l22.304,10.435c1.213,0.571,1.918,1.971,1.595,3.137l0,0
      C651.1,226.236,649.859,226.717,648.639,226.155z"/>
    </g>
    <g opacity="0.4">
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M662.025,283.795l-13.07-6.114c-1.205-0.567-1.925-1.972-1.587-3.134l0,0
      c0.323-1.167,1.572-1.653,2.792-1.077l13.063,6.105c1.212,0.567,1.924,1.971,1.594,3.134l0,0
      C664.479,283.876,663.229,284.357,662.025,283.795z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M693.138,298.348l-19.263-9.014c-1.213-0.562-1.925-1.967-1.587-3.129l0,0
      c0.331-1.166,1.58-1.653,2.792-1.085l19.264,9.014c1.22,0.562,1.924,1.966,1.594,3.129l0,0
      C695.607,298.434,694.351,298.915,693.138,298.348z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M639.243,333.193l-13.063-6.105c-1.204-0.562-1.924-1.972-1.587-3.134l0,0
      c0.323-1.166,1.58-1.648,2.784-1.085l13.062,6.109c1.227,0.572,1.94,1.977,1.602,3.134l0,0
      C641.711,333.278,640.455,333.76,639.243,333.193z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M666.984,346.179l-19.256-9.014c-1.22-0.567-1.932-1.972-1.602-3.138l0,0
      c0.338-1.162,1.594-1.652,2.799-1.081l19.263,9.01c1.22,0.567,1.918,1.976,1.594,3.134l0,0
      C669.453,346.26,668.196,346.741,666.984,346.179z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M623.483,275.776l-8.162-3.819c-1.205-0.567-1.925-1.971-1.587-3.133l0,0
      c0.316-1.167,1.572-1.648,2.792-1.086l8.155,3.824c1.219,0.567,1.933,1.967,1.594,3.129l0,0
      C625.945,275.861,624.696,276.343,623.483,275.776z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M648.639,297.544l-24.942-11.653c-1.205-0.572-1.933-1.977-1.595-3.138l0,0
      c0.331-1.167,1.587-1.653,2.799-1.082l24.935,11.662c1.212,0.567,1.924,1.972,1.594,3.134l0,0
      C651.093,297.63,649.851,298.115,648.639,297.544z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M626.833,307.368l-8.177-3.819c-1.212-0.562-1.917-1.967-1.579-3.134l0,0
      c0.316-1.157,1.572-1.647,2.784-1.081l8.163,3.819c1.212,0.562,1.939,1.966,1.601,3.129l0,0
      C629.295,307.454,628.031,307.939,626.833,307.368z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M671.187,368.156l-21.791-10.191c-1.219-0.567-1.933-1.981-1.602-3.138l0,0
      c0.338-1.166,1.594-1.647,2.799-1.081l21.805,10.2c1.204,0.562,1.918,1.961,1.58,3.129l0,0
      C673.655,368.237,672.406,368.723,671.187,368.156z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M618.877,323.669l-5.238-2.453c-1.219-0.567-1.932-1.966-1.594-3.138l0,0
      c0.331-1.166,1.58-1.642,2.792-1.076l5.246,2.453c1.204,0.557,1.918,1.961,1.572,3.134l0,0
      C621.346,323.754,620.09,324.235,618.877,323.669z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M615.101,341.927l-6.502-3.044c-1.212-0.567-1.924-1.971-1.587-3.137l0,0
      c0.33-1.163,1.579-1.643,2.784-1.082l6.516,3.043c1.205,0.567,1.918,1.967,1.58,3.138l0,0
      C617.562,342.013,616.321,342.493,615.101,341.927z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M640.425,353.765l-17.162-8.029c-1.22-0.567-1.917-1.962-1.587-3.138l0,0
      c0.323-1.157,1.58-1.642,2.784-1.072l17.155,8.025c1.212,0.567,1.925,1.971,1.602,3.129l0,0
      C642.88,353.846,641.623,354.331,640.425,353.765z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M618.422,353.484l-12.342-5.777c-1.205-0.562-1.918-1.966-1.602-3.124l0,0
      c0.338-1.166,1.602-1.652,2.799-1.085l12.336,5.772c1.212,0.562,1.939,1.967,1.602,3.134l0,0
      C620.876,353.565,619.62,354.046,618.422,353.484z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M689.899,376.952l-7.927-3.71c-1.22-0.567-1.925-1.967-1.595-3.134l0,0
      c0.331-1.162,1.587-1.642,2.792-1.081l7.927,3.7c1.205,0.572,1.925,1.981,1.602,3.142l0,0
      C692.352,377.033,691.111,377.519,689.899,376.952z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M657.191,321.569l-21.798-10.192c-1.212-0.575-1.924-1.976-1.601-3.137l0,0
      c0.33-1.167,1.594-1.653,2.791-1.082l21.813,10.196c1.204,0.562,1.917,1.967,1.594,3.129l0,0
      C659.659,321.654,658.403,322.135,657.191,321.569z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M659.174,312.492l-37.998-17.773c-1.212-0.572-1.925-1.971-1.594-3.137l0,0
      c0.338-1.163,1.587-1.643,2.806-1.082l37.983,17.772c1.219,0.567,1.924,1.971,1.601,3.134l0,0
      C661.635,312.573,660.379,313.054,659.174,312.492z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M637.942,322.583l-21.797-10.2c-1.213-0.567-1.918-1.967-1.58-3.134l0,0
      c0.316-1.167,1.572-1.653,2.792-1.082l21.797,10.192c1.213,0.572,1.918,1.976,1.595,3.137l0,0
      C640.418,322.669,639.162,323.15,637.942,322.583z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M673.728,329.302l-7.934-3.705c-1.205-0.567-1.918-1.966-1.587-3.133l0,0
      c0.338-1.163,1.58-1.648,2.799-1.077l7.913,3.7c1.22,0.567,1.939,1.967,1.608,3.134l0,0
      C676.182,329.388,674.941,329.873,673.728,329.302z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M637.31,342.307l-26.191-12.257c-1.219-0.572-1.925-1.972-1.594-3.138l0,0
      c0.33-1.162,1.579-1.642,2.784-1.076l26.213,12.248c1.212,0.572,1.917,1.981,1.602,3.138l0,0
      C639.786,342.388,638.53,342.869,637.31,342.307z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M637.105,272.138l-19.27-9.014c-1.22-0.567-1.933-1.967-1.595-3.134l0,0
      c0.331-1.166,1.587-1.648,2.799-1.077l19.256,9.006c1.212,0.567,1.932,1.971,1.609,3.138l0,0
      C639.566,272.219,638.309,272.704,637.105,272.138z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M614.984,361.884l-22.32-10.438c-1.205-0.562-1.918-1.966-1.587-3.134l0,0
      c0.323-1.157,1.58-1.642,2.799-1.076l22.304,10.434c1.213,0.567,1.925,1.967,1.602,3.134l0,0
      C617.445,361.965,616.196,362.452,614.984,361.884z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
     <linearGradient id="SVGID_6_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="576.5303" y1="216.0653" x2="728.6089" y2="216.0653">
      <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#8F9493"/>
      <stop  offset="0.4845" style="stop-color:#C3CCCB"/>
      <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#8E9392"/>
     </linearGradient>
     <path fill="url(#SVGID_6_)" d="M692.867,167.272c-18.029-10.491-36.763-19.254-55.873-26.135l-37.85-13.634l-12.122,3.829
      c0,0,5.311,2.305,9.742,4.229l-17.97,60.932c0,0-16.935,49.616,41.847,107.899c11.27,0.624,21.137-0.019,29.769-1.557
      c-0.183,0.572-0.308,0.962-0.308,0.962l10.917-3.457c1.014-0.304,2.02-0.614,2.99-0.943l0.227-0.076h-0.014
      c36.565-12.41,44.051-42.273,44.051-42.273l20.336-68.988L692.867,167.272z"/>
     <linearGradient id="SVGID_7_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="587.0221" y1="160.3566" x2="728.6089" y2="160.3566">
      <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#8F9493"/>
      <stop  offset="0.4845" style="stop-color:#C3CCCB"/>
      <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#8E9392"/>
     </linearGradient>
     <path fill="url(#SVGID_7_)" d="M636.994,141.137l-37.85-13.634l-12.122,3.829c0,0,5.311,2.305,9.742,4.229l-6.517,22.106
      l67.472,35.544l58.767-1.319l12.123-3.834l-35.742-20.786C674.838,156.781,656.104,148.018,636.994,141.137z"/>
     <linearGradient id="SVGID_8_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="587.0221" y1="142.4773" x2="667.0354" y2="142.4773">
      <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#8F9493"/>
      <stop  offset="0.4845" style="stop-color:#C3CCCB"/>
      <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#8E9392"/>
     </linearGradient>
     <path fill="url(#SVGID_8_)" d="M654.832,157.452l12.203-3.781c-9.882-4.69-19.895-8.881-30.041-12.533l-37.85-13.634
      l-12.122,3.829c0,0,5.311,2.305,9.742,4.229l-0.382,1.305C619.979,145.247,654.832,157.452,654.832,157.452z"/>
     <linearGradient id="SVGID_9_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="634.7019" y1="157.1802" x2="676.285" y2="157.1802">
      <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#8F9493"/>
      <stop  offset="0.4845" style="stop-color:#C3CCCB"/>
      <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#8E9392"/>
     </linearGradient>
     <path display="none" fill="url(#SVGID_9_)" d="M657.426,149.28l-22.724,6.901l19.028,8.899l22.555-6.847
      C670.055,155.056,663.773,152.061,657.426,149.28z"/>
     <linearGradient id="SVGID_10_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="564.4077" y1="219.8938" x2="716.4862" y2="219.8938">
      <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#004D69"/>
      <stop  offset="0.4845" style="stop-color:#096A90"/>
      <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#00516E"/>
     </linearGradient>
     <path fill="url(#SVGID_10_)" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M696.151,260.87l20.336-68.979L680.737,171.1
      c-18.029-10.49-36.771-19.253-55.872-26.135l-37.843-13.633l-20.351,68.98c0,0-16.934,49.63,41.832,107.904
      C683.25,312.388,696.151,260.87,696.151,260.87z"/>
     <linearGradient id="SVGID_11_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="573.902" y1="221.445" x2="705.7823" y2="221.445">
      <stop  offset="0.0298" style="stop-color:#D6AF3E"/>
      <stop  offset="0.1466" style="stop-color:#D7B03C"/>
      <stop  offset="0.1887" style="stop-color:#D9B335"/>
      <stop  offset="0.2187" style="stop-color:#DEB82A"/>
      <stop  offset="0.2428" style="stop-color:#E4BF19"/>
      <stop  offset="0.2633" style="stop-color:#EDC903"/>
      <stop  offset="0.2658" style="stop-color:#EECA00"/>
      <stop  offset="0.5359" style="stop-color:#B8983E"/>
      <stop  offset="0.8869" style="stop-color:#E5B83B"/>
      <stop  offset="0.9992" style="stop-color:#B48D3D"/>
     </linearGradient>
     <linearGradient id="SVGID_12_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="573.402" y1="221.3699" x2="706.3729" y2="221.3699">
      <stop  offset="0.0298" style="stop-color:#D6AF3E"/>
      <stop  offset="0.1466" style="stop-color:#D7B03C"/>
      <stop  offset="0.1887" style="stop-color:#D9B335"/>
      <stop  offset="0.2187" style="stop-color:#DEB82A"/>
      <stop  offset="0.2428" style="stop-color:#E4BF19"/>
      <stop  offset="0.2633" style="stop-color:#EDC903"/>
      <stop  offset="0.2658" style="stop-color:#EECA00"/>
      <stop  offset="0.5359" style="stop-color:#B8983E"/>
      <stop  offset="0.8869" style="stop-color:#E5B83B"/>
      <stop  offset="0.9992" style="stop-color:#B48D3D"/>
     </linearGradient>
     <path fill="url(#SVGID_11_)" stroke="url(#SVGID_12_)" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M613.242,300.725
      c-26.559-27.325-35.419-52.193-38.144-68.446c-3.049-18.163,0.691-29.845,0.72-29.925l17.772-60.24l27.418,9.882
      c18.485,6.652,36.719,15.181,54.212,25.357l30.563,17.777l-18.874,63.96l-0.066,0.248c-0.029,0.119-3.056,11.296-13.819,21.886
      C659.138,294.881,639.022,301.429,613.242,300.725z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
     <linearGradient id="SVGID_13_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="622.3227" y1="173.6688" x2="628.4402" y2="173.6688">
      <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#5B1516"/>
      <stop  offset="0.0084" style="stop-color:#611617"/>
      <stop  offset="0.0602" style="stop-color:#831D1C"/>
      <stop  offset="0.1131" style="stop-color:#9E2321"/>
      <stop  offset="0.1669" style="stop-color:#B12724"/>
      <stop  offset="0.2221" style="stop-color:#BC2925"/>
      <stop  offset="0.2809" style="stop-color:#C02A26"/>
      <stop  offset="0.8213" style="stop-color:#A02D2E"/>
      <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#C24535"/>
     </linearGradient>
     <path fill="url(#SVGID_13_)" d="M622.521,172.329c-0.595,1.477,0.191,3.277,1.771,4.019c1.594,0.738,3.357,0.148,3.952-1.343
      c0.596-1.476-0.213-3.271-1.785-4.019C624.872,170.252,623.109,170.848,622.521,172.329z"/>
     <linearGradient id="SVGID_14_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="613.1047" y1="169.3577" x2="619.2191" y2="169.3577">
      <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#5B1516"/>
      <stop  offset="0.0084" style="stop-color:#611617"/>
      <stop  offset="0.0602" style="stop-color:#831D1C"/>
      <stop  offset="0.1131" style="stop-color:#9E2321"/>
      <stop  offset="0.1669" style="stop-color:#B12724"/>
      <stop  offset="0.2221" style="stop-color:#BC2925"/>
      <stop  offset="0.2809" style="stop-color:#C02A26"/>
      <stop  offset="0.8213" style="stop-color:#A02D2E"/>
      <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#C24535"/>
     </linearGradient>
     <path fill="url(#SVGID_14_)" d="M613.308,168.014c-0.61,1.486,0.199,3.277,1.778,4.019c1.587,0.748,3.35,0.143,3.938-1.333
      c0.588-1.48-0.199-3.286-1.778-4.019C615.652,165.938,613.896,166.534,613.308,168.014z"/>
     <linearGradient id="SVGID_15_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="603.884" y1="165.0452" x2="610.0045" y2="165.0452">
      <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#5B1516"/>
      <stop  offset="0.0084" style="stop-color:#611617"/>
      <stop  offset="0.0602" style="stop-color:#831D1C"/>
      <stop  offset="0.1131" style="stop-color:#9E2321"/>
      <stop  offset="0.1669" style="stop-color:#B12724"/>
      <stop  offset="0.2221" style="stop-color:#BC2925"/>
      <stop  offset="0.2809" style="stop-color:#C02A26"/>
      <stop  offset="0.8213" style="stop-color:#A02D2E"/>
      <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#C24535"/>
     </linearGradient>
     <path fill="url(#SVGID_15_)" d="M604.081,163.709c-0.595,1.481,0.206,3.281,1.785,4.014c1.58,0.743,3.358,0.138,3.946-1.338
      c0.587-1.476-0.214-3.276-1.786-4.019C606.447,161.624,604.669,162.229,604.081,163.709z"/>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Lo que busco es que al pasar el cursor el icono (imagen) este desaparezca y aparezca el texto "Apartado 1" sobre la zona gris del triángulo. Intenté hacerlo pero solo conseguí aplicar el efecto hover al triángulo. ¿Puede lograrse mediante JavaScript?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden.

Comment: ¿Qué texto quieres mostrar? ¿Dentro o fuera de la imagen? ¿Puedes usar JavaScript?

Comment: El texto a mostrar es Apartado 1 y  debe de ir fuera de la imagen. En lo que respecta a JavaScript, si puede utilizarse.

Comment: @Blanca Si el texto es parte de la imagen, podría hacerse sin necesidad de JavaScript (creo, tendría que hacer pruebas). Si el texto está fuera de la imagen, depende de cómo lo quieras tener.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro el texto va separado de la imagen.El único requerimiento es  que la imagen no se vea al momento de pasar el cursor.

Comment: @Blanca no comprendo a qué te refieres con "El único requerimiento es que la imagen no se vea al momento de pasar el cursor"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo se podría hacerse teniendo el texto dentro de la propia imagen SVG:

- Añade el texto en un `<text>`. Lo he colocado al final de todos los elementos para que al quede encima de todo, y además lo he posicionado en el centro de la imagen, aunque puedes ponerlo donde quieras.
- Usando el selector de hermano no adyacente (`~`) aplico los estilos que ya tenías para que se muestre (le he puesto un tamaño más grande para que se vea).
- Opcional: le he quitado los eventos del ratón al grupo del icono para que no se vaya el texto cuando pases por encima.

Con esos tres cambios, el código queda así:

```css
.apartados {}

.apartados:hover {
  fill: #ffcd00;
}

.apartados:hover ~ text,
.apartados:hover + g {
  fill-opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}

text {
  fill-opacity: 0;
  font-family: OpenSans-ExtraboldItalic;
  font-size: 65px;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.0" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1366 768" enable-background="new 0 0 1366 768" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Apartado_5">
 <defs>
  <polygon  id="SVGID_1_" points="219,54 1103,54 661.003,627   "/>
 </defs>
 <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
  <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"  overflow="visible"/>
 </clipPath>
 <linearGradient id="SVGID_3_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="219" y1="340.5" x2="1103" y2="340.5">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#8F9493"/>
  <stop  offset="0.4845" style="stop-color:#C3CCCB"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#8E9392"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="apartados" clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)" fill="url(#SVGID_3_)" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="219,54 1103,54 
  661.003,627  "/>
    
 <g id="icono_5_1_" clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)">
  <g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <path fill="#143B74" d="M790.094,147.851L672.824,90.783c-5.12-2.501-10.395-2.724-14.965-1.062v-0.005l-11.16,3.286h8.515
      c-1.638,2.21-2.931,4.848-3.74,7.881l-62.014,230.405c-3.512,13.058,3.056,28.226,14.664,33.878l117.283,57.068
      c1.25,0.605,2.499,1.072,3.74,1.41l-4.628,5.724l9.83-2.772h-0.008c5.767-2.091,10.455-7.171,12.416-14.458l62.014-230.419
      C808.284,168.671,801.716,153.499,790.094,147.851z"/>
     <path fill="#D0E6F6" d="M704.967,428.526l-117.262-57.074c-11.63-5.643-18.198-20.811-14.679-33.864l62.007-230.41
      c3.519-13.057,15.774-19.058,27.389-13.41l117.277,57.074c11.615,5.658,18.183,20.824,14.664,33.877l-61.999,230.405
      C728.851,428.187,716.582,434.182,704.967,428.526z"/>
     <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M705.172,421.968l-114.513-55.731c-9.029-4.395-14.128-16.186-11.41-26.334l61.668-229.148
      c2.733-10.153,12.269-14.814,21.306-10.424l114.507,55.735c9.028,4.396,14.149,16.187,11.402,26.334l-61.654,229.143
      C723.738,421.697,714.209,426.364,705.172,421.968z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
     <linearGradient id="SVGID_4_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="588.5148" y1="259.0109" x2="805.7188" y2="259.0109">
      <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#5D676B"/>
      <stop  offset="0.4845" style="stop-color:#808B90"/>
      <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#5D676B"/>
     </linearGradient>
     <path fill="url(#SVGID_4_)" d="M790.094,147.851L672.824,90.783c-5.12-2.501-10.395-2.724-14.965-1.062v-0.005l-11.16,3.286
      h8.515c-1.638,2.21-2.931,4.848-3.74,7.881l-62.014,230.405c-3.512,13.058,3.056,28.226,14.664,33.878l117.283,57.068
      c1.25,0.605,2.499,1.072,3.74,1.41l-4.628,5.724l9.83-2.772h-0.008c5.767-2.091,10.455-7.171,12.416-14.458l62.014-230.419
      C808.284,168.671,801.716,153.499,790.094,147.851z"/>
     <linearGradient id="SVGID_5_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="572.0767" y1="261.1499" x2="795.3118" y2="261.1499">
      <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#8F9493"/>
      <stop  offset="0.4845" style="stop-color:#C3CCCB"/>
      <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#8E9392"/>
     </linearGradient>
     <path fill="url(#SVGID_5_)" d="M704.967,428.526l-117.262-57.074c-11.63-5.643-18.198-20.811-14.679-33.864l62.007-230.41
      c3.519-13.057,15.774-19.058,27.389-13.41l117.277,57.074c11.615,5.658,18.183,20.824,14.664,33.877l-61.999,230.405
      C728.851,428.187,716.582,434.182,704.967,428.526z"/>
     <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M705.172,421.968l-114.513-55.731c-9.029-4.395-14.128-16.186-11.41-26.334l61.668-229.148
      c2.733-10.153,12.269-14.814,21.306-10.424l114.507,55.735c9.028,4.396,14.149,16.187,11.402,26.334l-61.654,229.143
      C723.738,421.697,714.209,426.364,705.172,421.968z"/>
    </g>
    <g opacity="0.4">
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M695.673,148.052l-13.062-6.11c-1.198-0.562-1.918-1.972-1.587-3.129l0,0
      c0.323-1.166,1.579-1.652,2.799-1.085l13.056,6.109c1.212,0.572,1.932,1.972,1.602,3.134l0,0
      C698.142,148.142,696.885,148.619,695.673,148.052z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M726.801,162.609l-19.255-9.005c-1.219-0.576-1.939-1.976-1.602-3.138l0,0
      c0.33-1.166,1.594-1.647,2.792-1.081l19.263,9.005c1.22,0.572,1.933,1.981,1.594,3.138l0,0
      C729.27,162.69,728.014,163.171,726.801,162.609z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M672.898,197.464l-13.056-6.11c-1.204-0.572-1.924-1.981-1.594-3.138l0,0
      c0.323-1.162,1.58-1.647,2.799-1.081l13.056,6.105c1.22,0.571,1.924,1.981,1.594,3.137l0,0
      C675.374,197.545,674.11,198.03,672.898,197.464z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M700.654,210.435l-19.263-9.01c-1.22-0.567-1.939-1.971-1.609-3.138l0,0
      c0.345-1.157,1.594-1.637,2.807-1.076l19.256,9.005c1.219,0.567,1.932,1.972,1.608,3.134l0,0
      C703.108,210.521,701.859,211.001,700.654,210.435z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M657.14,140.032l-8.163-3.814c-1.205-0.567-1.925-1.967-1.587-3.134l0,0
      c0.338-1.163,1.572-1.648,2.792-1.077l8.162,3.81c1.213,0.572,1.925,1.976,1.594,3.137l0,0
      C659.6,140.118,658.359,140.599,657.14,140.032z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M682.302,161.819l-24.942-11.667c-1.213-0.572-1.925-1.976-1.594-3.134l0,0
      c0.33-1.171,1.579-1.643,2.791-1.085l24.943,11.662c1.212,0.567,1.918,1.976,1.587,3.134l0,0
      C684.763,161.895,683.507,162.381,682.302,161.819z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M660.482,171.628l-8.163-3.814c-1.197-0.572-1.91-1.966-1.594-3.138l0,0
      c0.339-1.162,1.587-1.642,2.799-1.076l8.155,3.814c1.212,0.567,1.939,1.972,1.609,3.138l0,0
      C662.95,171.714,661.694,172.195,660.482,171.628z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M704.849,232.417l-21.791-10.191c-1.213-0.567-1.939-1.971-1.602-3.134l0,0
      c0.33-1.171,1.594-1.652,2.799-1.085l21.797,10.196c1.205,0.572,1.925,1.962,1.602,3.138l0,0
      C707.31,232.502,706.069,232.984,704.849,232.417z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M652.533,187.924l-5.246-2.447c-1.212-0.567-1.918-1.967-1.587-3.134l0,0
      c0.33-1.163,1.587-1.648,2.799-1.082l5.238,2.448c1.198,0.572,1.918,1.972,1.594,3.138l0,0
      C655.001,188.015,653.745,188.491,652.533,187.924z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M648.764,206.192l-6.502-3.048c-1.219-0.572-1.932-1.967-1.594-3.138l0,0
      c0.331-1.162,1.58-1.643,2.799-1.076l6.501,3.043c1.213,0.567,1.925,1.971,1.587,3.134l0,0
      C651.218,206.268,649.984,206.754,648.764,206.192z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M674.073,218.026l-17.154-8.029c-1.22-0.567-1.918-1.966-1.587-3.134l0,0
      c0.323-1.157,1.58-1.642,2.792-1.076l17.147,8.019c1.219,0.576,1.925,1.977,1.602,3.134l0,0
      C676.542,218.107,675.294,218.593,674.073,218.026z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M652.077,217.741l-12.328-5.758c-1.219-0.572-1.924-1.986-1.601-3.142l0,0
      c0.33-1.167,1.587-1.648,2.799-1.082l12.321,5.767c1.213,0.572,1.939,1.972,1.609,3.138l0,0
      C654.539,217.822,653.282,218.307,652.077,217.741z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M723.554,241.213l-7.92-3.705c-1.219-0.572-1.933-1.971-1.595-3.134l0,0
      c0.323-1.166,1.58-1.652,2.785-1.081l7.935,3.7c1.204,0.567,1.917,1.971,1.587,3.134l0,0
      C726.022,241.294,724.766,241.77,723.554,241.213z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M690.854,185.825l-21.805-10.191c-1.205-0.567-1.918-1.967-1.594-3.134l0,0
      c0.33-1.162,1.587-1.648,2.792-1.081l21.805,10.191c1.205,0.572,1.932,1.981,1.594,3.138l0,0
      C693.315,185.91,692.065,186.391,690.854,185.825z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M692.83,176.753l-37.983-17.772c-1.219-0.563-1.933-1.972-1.602-3.129l0,0
      c0.338-1.172,1.587-1.658,2.799-1.086l37.983,17.773c1.22,0.572,1.932,1.962,1.602,3.134l0,0
      C695.291,176.838,694.042,177.319,692.83,176.753z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M671.605,186.844l-21.797-10.2c-1.213-0.572-1.918-1.967-1.595-3.134l0,0
      c0.331-1.162,1.587-1.647,2.799-1.081l21.798,10.2c1.219,0.562,1.924,1.966,1.587,3.134l0,0
      C674.073,186.925,672.824,187.406,671.605,186.844z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M707.384,193.563l-7.927-3.705c-1.213-0.567-1.925-1.972-1.587-3.129l0,0
      c0.331-1.171,1.572-1.653,2.792-1.086l7.927,3.7c1.213,0.572,1.925,1.982,1.587,3.138l0,0
      C709.845,193.648,708.596,194.13,707.384,193.563z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M766.511,180.02l-7.913-3.7c-1.22-0.567-1.932-1.972-1.602-3.134l0,0
      c0.338-1.166,1.594-1.647,2.799-1.085l7.927,3.705c1.198,0.572,1.918,1.981,1.587,3.137l0,0
      C768.994,180.106,767.73,180.586,766.511,180.02z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M670.981,206.569l-26.206-12.258c-1.22-0.562-1.918-1.966-1.587-3.129l0,0
      c0.33-1.176,1.579-1.657,2.792-1.09l26.206,12.257c1.212,0.567,1.918,1.972,1.594,3.134l0,0
      C673.442,206.654,672.2,207.135,670.981,206.569z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M670.76,136.394l-19.263-9c-1.22-0.576-1.925-1.981-1.602-3.134l0,0
      c0.338-1.176,1.594-1.652,2.799-1.09l19.264,9.015c1.212,0.567,1.939,1.962,1.602,3.134l0,0
      C673.222,136.479,671.965,136.965,670.76,136.394z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M648.639,226.155l-22.312-10.443c-1.205-0.572-1.925-1.967-1.587-3.138l0,0
      c0.331-1.158,1.58-1.643,2.799-1.077l22.304,10.435c1.213,0.571,1.918,1.971,1.595,3.137l0,0
      C651.1,226.236,649.859,226.717,648.639,226.155z"/>
    </g>
    <g opacity="0.4">
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M662.025,283.795l-13.07-6.114c-1.205-0.567-1.925-1.972-1.587-3.134l0,0
      c0.323-1.167,1.572-1.653,2.792-1.077l13.063,6.105c1.212,0.567,1.924,1.971,1.594,3.134l0,0
      C664.479,283.876,663.229,284.357,662.025,283.795z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M693.138,298.348l-19.263-9.014c-1.213-0.562-1.925-1.967-1.587-3.129l0,0
      c0.331-1.166,1.58-1.653,2.792-1.085l19.264,9.014c1.22,0.562,1.924,1.966,1.594,3.129l0,0
      C695.607,298.434,694.351,298.915,693.138,298.348z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M639.243,333.193l-13.063-6.105c-1.204-0.562-1.924-1.972-1.587-3.134l0,0
      c0.323-1.166,1.58-1.648,2.784-1.085l13.062,6.109c1.227,0.572,1.94,1.977,1.602,3.134l0,0
      C641.711,333.278,640.455,333.76,639.243,333.193z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M666.984,346.179l-19.256-9.014c-1.22-0.567-1.932-1.972-1.602-3.138l0,0
      c0.338-1.162,1.594-1.652,2.799-1.081l19.263,9.01c1.22,0.567,1.918,1.976,1.594,3.134l0,0
      C669.453,346.26,668.196,346.741,666.984,346.179z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M623.483,275.776l-8.162-3.819c-1.205-0.567-1.925-1.971-1.587-3.133l0,0
      c0.316-1.167,1.572-1.648,2.792-1.086l8.155,3.824c1.219,0.567,1.933,1.967,1.594,3.129l0,0
      C625.945,275.861,624.696,276.343,623.483,275.776z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M648.639,297.544l-24.942-11.653c-1.205-0.572-1.933-1.977-1.595-3.138l0,0
      c0.331-1.167,1.587-1.653,2.799-1.082l24.935,11.662c1.212,0.567,1.924,1.972,1.594,3.134l0,0
      C651.093,297.63,649.851,298.115,648.639,297.544z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M626.833,307.368l-8.177-3.819c-1.212-0.562-1.917-1.967-1.579-3.134l0,0
      c0.316-1.157,1.572-1.647,2.784-1.081l8.163,3.819c1.212,0.562,1.939,1.966,1.601,3.129l0,0
      C629.295,307.454,628.031,307.939,626.833,307.368z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M671.187,368.156l-21.791-10.191c-1.219-0.567-1.933-1.981-1.602-3.138l0,0
      c0.338-1.166,1.594-1.647,2.799-1.081l21.805,10.2c1.204,0.562,1.918,1.961,1.58,3.129l0,0
      C673.655,368.237,672.406,368.723,671.187,368.156z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M618.877,323.669l-5.238-2.453c-1.219-0.567-1.932-1.966-1.594-3.138l0,0
      c0.331-1.166,1.58-1.642,2.792-1.076l5.246,2.453c1.204,0.557,1.918,1.961,1.572,3.134l0,0
      C621.346,323.754,620.09,324.235,618.877,323.669z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M615.101,341.927l-6.502-3.044c-1.212-0.567-1.924-1.971-1.587-3.137l0,0
      c0.33-1.163,1.579-1.643,2.784-1.082l6.516,3.043c1.205,0.567,1.918,1.967,1.58,3.138l0,0
      C617.562,342.013,616.321,342.493,615.101,341.927z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M640.425,353.765l-17.162-8.029c-1.22-0.567-1.917-1.962-1.587-3.138l0,0
      c0.323-1.157,1.58-1.642,2.784-1.072l17.155,8.025c1.212,0.567,1.925,1.971,1.602,3.129l0,0
      C642.88,353.846,641.623,354.331,640.425,353.765z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M618.422,353.484l-12.342-5.777c-1.205-0.562-1.918-1.966-1.602-3.124l0,0
      c0.338-1.166,1.602-1.652,2.799-1.085l12.336,5.772c1.212,0.562,1.939,1.967,1.602,3.134l0,0
      C620.876,353.565,619.62,354.046,618.422,353.484z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M689.899,376.952l-7.927-3.71c-1.22-0.567-1.925-1.967-1.595-3.134l0,0
      c0.331-1.162,1.587-1.642,2.792-1.081l7.927,3.7c1.205,0.572,1.925,1.981,1.602,3.142l0,0
      C692.352,377.033,691.111,377.519,689.899,376.952z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M657.191,321.569l-21.798-10.192c-1.212-0.575-1.924-1.976-1.601-3.137l0,0
      c0.33-1.167,1.594-1.653,2.791-1.082l21.813,10.196c1.204,0.562,1.917,1.967,1.594,3.129l0,0
      C659.659,321.654,658.403,322.135,657.191,321.569z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M659.174,312.492l-37.998-17.773c-1.212-0.572-1.925-1.971-1.594-3.137l0,0
      c0.338-1.163,1.587-1.643,2.806-1.082l37.983,17.772c1.219,0.567,1.924,1.971,1.601,3.134l0,0
      C661.635,312.573,660.379,313.054,659.174,312.492z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M637.942,322.583l-21.797-10.2c-1.213-0.567-1.918-1.967-1.58-3.134l0,0
      c0.316-1.167,1.572-1.653,2.792-1.082l21.797,10.192c1.213,0.572,1.918,1.976,1.595,3.137l0,0
      C640.418,322.669,639.162,323.15,637.942,322.583z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M673.728,329.302l-7.934-3.705c-1.205-0.567-1.918-1.966-1.587-3.133l0,0
      c0.338-1.163,1.58-1.648,2.799-1.077l7.913,3.7c1.22,0.567,1.939,1.967,1.608,3.134l0,0
      C676.182,329.388,674.941,329.873,673.728,329.302z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M637.31,342.307l-26.191-12.257c-1.219-0.572-1.925-1.972-1.594-3.138l0,0
      c0.33-1.162,1.579-1.642,2.784-1.076l26.213,12.248c1.212,0.572,1.917,1.981,1.602,3.138l0,0
      C639.786,342.388,638.53,342.869,637.31,342.307z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M637.105,272.138l-19.27-9.014c-1.22-0.567-1.933-1.967-1.595-3.134l0,0
      c0.331-1.166,1.587-1.648,2.799-1.077l19.256,9.006c1.212,0.567,1.932,1.971,1.609,3.138l0,0
      C639.566,272.219,638.309,272.704,637.105,272.138z"/>
     <path fill="#0A080A" d="M614.984,361.884l-22.32-10.438c-1.205-0.562-1.918-1.966-1.587-3.134l0,0
      c0.323-1.157,1.58-1.642,2.799-1.076l22.304,10.434c1.213,0.567,1.925,1.967,1.602,3.134l0,0
      C617.445,361.965,616.196,362.452,614.984,361.884z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
     <linearGradient id="SVGID_6_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="576.5303" y1="216.0653" x2="728.6089" y2="216.0653">
      <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#8F9493"/>
      <stop  offset="0.4845" style="stop-color:#C3CCCB"/>
      <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#8E9392"/>
     </linearGradient>
     <path fill="url(#SVGID_6_)" d="M692.867,167.272c-18.029-10.491-36.763-19.254-55.873-26.135l-37.85-13.634l-12.122,3.829
      c0,0,5.311,2.305,9.742,4.229l-17.97,60.932c0,0-16.935,49.616,41.847,107.899c11.27,0.624,21.137-0.019,29.769-1.557
      c-0.183,0.572-0.308,0.962-0.308,0.962l10.917-3.457c1.014-0.304,2.02-0.614,2.99-0.943l0.227-0.076h-0.014
      c36.565-12.41,44.051-42.273,44.051-42.273l20.336-68.988L692.867,167.272z"/>
     <linearGradient id="SVGID_7_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="587.0221" y1="160.3566" x2="728.6089" y2="160.3566">
      <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#8F9493"/>
      <stop  offset="0.4845" style="stop-color:#C3CCCB"/>
      <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#8E9392"/>
     </linearGradient>
     <path fill="url(#SVGID_7_)" d="M636.994,141.137l-37.85-13.634l-12.122,3.829c0,0,5.311,2.305,9.742,4.229l-6.517,22.106
      l67.472,35.544l58.767-1.319l12.123-3.834l-35.742-20.786C674.838,156.781,656.104,148.018,636.994,141.137z"/>
     <linearGradient id="SVGID_8_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="587.0221" y1="142.4773" x2="667.0354" y2="142.4773">
      <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#8F9493"/>
      <stop  offset="0.4845" style="stop-color:#C3CCCB"/>
      <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#8E9392"/>
     </linearGradient>
     <path fill="url(#SVGID_8_)" d="M654.832,157.452l12.203-3.781c-9.882-4.69-19.895-8.881-30.041-12.533l-37.85-13.634
      l-12.122,3.829c0,0,5.311,2.305,9.742,4.229l-0.382,1.305C619.979,145.247,654.832,157.452,654.832,157.452z"/>
     <linearGradient id="SVGID_9_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="634.7019" y1="157.1802" x2="676.285" y2="157.1802">
      <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#8F9493"/>
      <stop  offset="0.4845" style="stop-color:#C3CCCB"/>
      <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#8E9392"/>
     </linearGradient>
     <path display="none" fill="url(#SVGID_9_)" d="M657.426,149.28l-22.724,6.901l19.028,8.899l22.555-6.847
      C670.055,155.056,663.773,152.061,657.426,149.28z"/>
     <linearGradient id="SVGID_10_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="564.4077" y1="219.8938" x2="716.4862" y2="219.8938">
      <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#004D69"/>
      <stop  offset="0.4845" style="stop-color:#096A90"/>
      <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#00516E"/>
     </linearGradient>
     <path fill="url(#SVGID_10_)" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M696.151,260.87l20.336-68.979L680.737,171.1
      c-18.029-10.49-36.771-19.253-55.872-26.135l-37.843-13.633l-20.351,68.98c0,0-16.934,49.63,41.832,107.904
      C683.25,312.388,696.151,260.87,696.151,260.87z"/>
     <linearGradient id="SVGID_11_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="573.902" y1="221.445" x2="705.7823" y2="221.445">
      <stop  offset="0.0298" style="stop-color:#D6AF3E"/>
      <stop  offset="0.1466" style="stop-color:#D7B03C"/>
      <stop  offset="0.1887" style="stop-color:#D9B335"/>
      <stop  offset="0.2187" style="stop-color:#DEB82A"/>
      <stop  offset="0.2428" style="stop-color:#E4BF19"/>
      <stop  offset="0.2633" style="stop-color:#EDC903"/>
      <stop  offset="0.2658" style="stop-color:#EECA00"/>
      <stop  offset="0.5359" style="stop-color:#B8983E"/>
      <stop  offset="0.8869" style="stop-color:#E5B83B"/>
      <stop  offset="0.9992" style="stop-color:#B48D3D"/>
     </linearGradient>
     <linearGradient id="SVGID_12_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="573.402" y1="221.3699" x2="706.3729" y2="221.3699">
      <stop  offset="0.0298" style="stop-color:#D6AF3E"/>
      <stop  offset="0.1466" style="stop-color:#D7B03C"/>
      <stop  offset="0.1887" style="stop-color:#D9B335"/>
      <stop  offset="0.2187" style="stop-color:#DEB82A"/>
      <stop  offset="0.2428" style="stop-color:#E4BF19"/>
      <stop  offset="0.2633" style="stop-color:#EDC903"/>
      <stop  offset="0.2658" style="stop-color:#EECA00"/>
      <stop  offset="0.5359" style="stop-color:#B8983E"/>
      <stop  offset="0.8869" style="stop-color:#E5B83B"/>
      <stop  offset="0.9992" style="stop-color:#B48D3D"/>
     </linearGradient>
     <path fill="url(#SVGID_11_)" stroke="url(#SVGID_12_)" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M613.242,300.725
      c-26.559-27.325-35.419-52.193-38.144-68.446c-3.049-18.163,0.691-29.845,0.72-29.925l17.772-60.24l27.418,9.882
      c18.485,6.652,36.719,15.181,54.212,25.357l30.563,17.777l-18.874,63.96l-0.066,0.248c-0.029,0.119-3.056,11.296-13.819,21.886
      C659.138,294.881,639.022,301.429,613.242,300.725z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
     <linearGradient id="SVGID_13_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="622.3227" y1="173.6688" x2="628.4402" y2="173.6688">
      <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#5B1516"/>
      <stop  offset="0.0084" style="stop-color:#611617"/>
      <stop  offset="0.0602" style="stop-color:#831D1C"/>
      <stop  offset="0.1131" style="stop-color:#9E2321"/>
      <stop  offset="0.1669" style="stop-color:#B12724"/>
      <stop  offset="0.2221" style="stop-color:#BC2925"/>
      <stop  offset="0.2809" style="stop-color:#C02A26"/>
      <stop  offset="0.8213" style="stop-color:#A02D2E"/>
      <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#C24535"/>
     </linearGradient>
     <path fill="url(#SVGID_13_)" d="M622.521,172.329c-0.595,1.477,0.191,3.277,1.771,4.019c1.594,0.738,3.357,0.148,3.952-1.343
      c0.596-1.476-0.213-3.271-1.785-4.019C624.872,170.252,623.109,170.848,622.521,172.329z"/>
     <linearGradient id="SVGID_14_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="613.1047" y1="169.3577" x2="619.2191" y2="169.3577">
      <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#5B1516"/>
      <stop  offset="0.0084" style="stop-color:#611617"/>
      <stop  offset="0.0602" style="stop-color:#831D1C"/>
      <stop  offset="0.1131" style="stop-color:#9E2321"/>
      <stop  offset="0.1669" style="stop-color:#B12724"/>
      <stop  offset="0.2221" style="stop-color:#BC2925"/>
      <stop  offset="0.2809" style="stop-color:#C02A26"/>
      <stop  offset="0.8213" style="stop-color:#A02D2E"/>
      <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#C24535"/>
     </linearGradient>
     <path fill="url(#SVGID_14_)" d="M613.308,168.014c-0.61,1.486,0.199,3.277,1.778,4.019c1.587,0.748,3.35,0.143,3.938-1.333
      c0.588-1.48-0.199-3.286-1.778-4.019C615.652,165.938,613.896,166.534,613.308,168.014z"/>
     <linearGradient id="SVGID_15_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="603.884" y1="165.0452" x2="610.0045" y2="165.0452">
      <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#5B1516"/>
      <stop  offset="0.0084" style="stop-color:#611617"/>
      <stop  offset="0.0602" style="stop-color:#831D1C"/>
      <stop  offset="0.1131" style="stop-color:#9E2321"/>
      <stop  offset="0.1669" style="stop-color:#B12724"/>
      <stop  offset="0.2221" style="stop-color:#BC2925"/>
      <stop  offset="0.2809" style="stop-color:#C02A26"/>
      <stop  offset="0.8213" style="stop-color:#A02D2E"/>
      <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#C24535"/>
     </linearGradient>
     <path fill="url(#SVGID_15_)" d="M604.081,163.709c-0.595,1.481,0.206,3.281,1.785,4.014c1.58,0.743,3.358,0.138,3.946-1.338
      c0.587-1.476-0.214-3.276-1.786-4.019C606.447,161.624,604.669,162.229,604.081,163.709z"/>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
  <text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">Apartado 1</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Estaba tratando de responder esta pregunta :D
Si quisiera que la imagen con ID `#icono_5_1_` desapareciera al hacer hover cómo podría hacerlo? Justo en ese punto me frené.

Comment: Es decir, sé como hacerlo, pero que afecte desde el hover en el polígono y no sobre la imagen

Comment: @JheymanMejia puedes hacerlo con `pointer-events:none`: de ese modo el efecto del ratón por encima de la imagen se ignora (y el texto no desaparece).

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de darle solución a mi pregunta @AlvaroMontoro me ha sido de mucha ayuda! Saludos :)